# laravel cashier with stripe no monthly plan error

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I am having trouble using laravel cashier with stripe new product and plan integration. So i created a product and within that product i created a plan. but when i submit the request to i get an error checked my database the user table contains the card information the subscription table is empty. How do integrate laravel cashier with stripe new system product & plan?

---

error:

```
 No such plan: Monthly
```

---

here my code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $token = $request->stripeToken;

    auth()->user()->newSubscription('main', 'Monthly')->create($token);

    return 'Done';
}
```

---

Comment: Did you find any solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a product on stripe(when creating it you can set the billing cycle). Once you have created the product on stripe it will then have a product ID. Instead of using the nickname you have assigned it on stripe you need to use the ID like so

```
$nickname = 'Monthly';
$plan_id = 'plan_xxxxxxxxxxx';

auth()->user()->newSubscription($nickname, $plan_id)->create($request->stripeToken);
```